# Character Map has Tai Viet listed

Tags: fonts, xkb

I see Tai Viet in the character map. My question is how to have this show up in the Text Entry list so I can use this language

Comment: Have you tried pressing the "+" sign and add it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no keyboard layout named *Tai Viet*. You can make some extra keyboard layouts available in *Text Entry* by running the command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources show-all-sources true
```

You may also want to install the `ibus-m17n` package, which (next time you log in) will make a few IBus input methods available for typing Tai and Vietnamese languages.